# Optimising Old AS3 Flash Project

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, flash, flash-cs5

I have an old SWF project file which is a series of png sequence to produce a 3D tour of numerous stadiums (If you can get it to load http://tinyurl.com/7h2zpcb). When I initially created it I never intended it to be published on the web (it was a university project) however I now would quite like to show it on the internet. The structure is of a main timeline with 4 stadiums each with a png sequence, then, when clicking on one of the stadiums, 4 more png sequences. The only problem is that it is all in one file and is over 12mb, plus has no pre-loader.

It is written in AS3 and is rather complicated as I used movie names and trimming to have reusable functions. It does however have global variables already set-up if this could help.

I have 2 questions. First, is there an easy method of separating out the project movies to 5 individual swf files. i.e main timeline, and each individual png sequence? Or will I need to copy and paste and copy assets over to each FLA file?

Secondly, would it just be easier to try using a preloaded and hoping that users wait for the project to download?

If you have any thoughts on this please give them. Is there a way to optimise the project in another way I am unaware of? As a side note there are a lot of pngs and total over 300mb when combined so I think XML is out of the question?

Thank you for your time. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Why not have a look into a 3D framework like [Papervision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) and set up your stadiums as skinned 3D objects? The size would be reduced drastically when compared to large sequences of PNGs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have not used Flash in about a year and I've never used PaperVision3D. Do you think it will be very time consuming to learn how to do it or can it be a largely automated process?

Comment: Hmmm.. To be honest, I think taking the time to learn Papervision and then implementing it where required in your project will be not only likely less time consuming than your approach, but also beneficial to your skillset.

Comment: @user1166885 it looks like a huge part of that 22.4 MB swf is images, looking through the images, it looks like there's a ton of un-used ones in there (or ones I can't figure out how to get to in the swf) for fly-throughs of the stadiums and break-downs of the levels of the stadiums.  Although Marty's suggestion is a good one (also check out Away3d or alternativa 3d as options) you might be able to significantly reduce the size of the swf by taking out all of those un-used images if you don't plan on showing them anywhere.  Took 17 seconds to download here would def do a preloader at least.

Comment: don't use papervision. it's old, look into any of the newer engines like away3d or alternativa.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses once again. Very helpful. Shaunhusain, how did you see that a large proportion of my images were unused? I am pretty unfamiliar with debugging Flash projects... 

Am I right in thinking the best way to clean-up my project is just right clicking in the project panel and choosing select unused? then deleting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness' sake. 
I did some research and tests and realised the time it would take to change the project to use any other technology would be too great for my needs. I simply just added a pre-loader to the site and saved myself a lot of extra time. When linking to the site I affix a message explaining that is for an offline installation and there may be a long load-time.

Hopefully this will help others in the future.

Thank you to Marty Wallace, shaunhusain and grapefrukt for their time and advice on this.